# Treeview drag and drop with a gtk CellRenderer in python

Tags: python, pygtk, gtktreeview, cellrenderer

When extending a gtk cell renderer such as `gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` in python, what needs to be done to make sure drag and drop works?

Drag and drop works for `gtk.CellRendererText` but not for my custom CellRender where I have extended `gtk.CellRendererPixbuf`.

Comment: What version of PyGTK and the GTK runtime are you using, and on what operating system? There are a few versions of GTK that break drag-and-drop in some situations on Microsoft Windows..